# How to get the charater at a specific position of a string in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, basic

I want to  get a character available at specific position  in Visual Basic for example the string is "APPLE".

I want to get the 3rd character in the string which is "P".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at a string as an array of Chars. The characters are indexed from 0 to the number of characters minus 1.

```
' For the 3rd character (the second P):

Dim s As String = "APPLE"
Dim ch As Char =  s(2) ' = 'P',  where s(0) is "A"
```

Or

```
Dim ch2 As Char = s.Chars(2) 'According to @schlebe's comment
```

Or

```
Dim substr As String = s.Substring(2, 1) 's.Substring(0, 1) is "A"
```

Or

```
Dim substr As String = Mid(s, 3, 1) 'Mid(s, 1, 1) is "A" (this is a relict from VB6)
```

Note: Use the first variant if you want to return a `Char`. The two others return a `String` of length 1. The common .NET way available in all the languages is to use the method `Substring`, where as the function `Mid` is VB specific and was introduced in order to facilitate the transition from VB6 to VB.NET.

Comment: Thanks m8. that's exactly what i was wanted to do.

Comment: You can also add Dim ch As Char =  s.Chars(3) '

Answer (score 1):

You also can get a char in a string by index of this char.

```
Dim s As String = "APPLE"
Dim c As Char = GetChar(s,4) ' = 'L' index = 1~
```